# My ubuntu sony laptop connects to wifi but can't load any data

Tags: 14.04, wireless, internet, router, netgear

**New Problem**

I am now able to access the internet but, when I connect to **netgear** router NO data is recieved and I can't also ping my router.This does not happen with any other router like DLINK or my phone's HOTSPOT. PLEASE can anyone help where the problem is.

The below problem is solved.

I have Sony vaio laptop having installed Ubuntu 14.04 on it. Laptop can connect to the wifi router but when browser is opened I get `the Web page is not available` error.

I did

```
$ ping google.com
ping: unknown host google.com
```

I ping my laptop. That returned success. But when I ping some other IPs it says **destination host unavailable**

This error started since I hard reset my router

**[Edited]**

```
$ lspi -knn | grep Net -A2
02:00.0 Network controller [0280] : Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0032] (rev 01)
Subsystem : Foxconn Interntional , Inc Device [105b: e044]
kernel driver in use : ath9k
```

I think I have messed up some thing  because of trying too many solution.  Is there any way like we have `factory reset` in mobile phones...so that I can be able to start again.
 One thing I can

```
ping 8.8.8.8
```

with 100% success

**Edited 2015-06-05**

This is what I tried on terminal

```
sudo lshw -c network
ifconfig
sudo service network-manager restart
sudo service networking restart
sudo /etc/ini.d/networking restart
sudo ifconfig wlan0 down
sudo service networking restart
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
sudo ifconfig wlan0 down
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
sudo apt-get remove --purge resolvconf
sudo dpkg --configure -a
lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
lsb_release -rcd ; uname -r;
lspci -nnk  | grep -iA2 net
lsmod rfkill list all nmcli nm status
nmcli nm enabled true
echo 'options ath9k nohwcrypt=1' sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf
rfkill list
```

Output of `route -vn`

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 br0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 br0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 br0
```

The command `ping 192.168.1.1` does not give anything! After some time I press Ctrl+C and all this gives me 100% data loss.

How should I proceed?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24513/discussion-on-question-by-learner-my-ubuntu-sony-laptop-connects-to-wifi-but-can).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hello To all those viewed this post. This issue was solved. People commenting on the post made me to detect the point where the error was caused.

This is what I made mistakes

> I unistall the resolvconf file

And then I tried some one's answer, Which suggested that to change the Proxy settings of the Network. I did as per his suggestion.

Then People on Reddit suggested to again install the `resolvconf` file. I installed manually.

But then the issue was with the `Proxy change` I did it. He then suggested me to change it to none and Boom the problem was solved.

And really I made so many wrong changes that I did in terminal as listed above.

*Today What I learned is, first check the command for which purpose it is used to execute and then execute.*

Hearty Thanks to all once again

**Solved**

Comment: The best part of this is "first check the command for which purpose it is used to execute and then execute." Bravo